# Extremely Slow Logon and Light Blue Screen (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, performance, login

I have been using my computer completely normally for the past week.  About 2 days ago, I noticed an issue where, after I authenticated with an external biometric reader, it would say "Welcome" for way longer than it normally did.  Afterward, it would show a completely blank light blue screen for about 30 seconds.  Following that, it would boot into my desktop like nothing happened.

I have used the biometric software for well over 3 months, and I haven't had an issue with it before.

**Computer specs:**

- Gigabyte H170M-DS3H Motherboard
- Intel i5-6400 @ 2.7 GHz
- Sapphire Radeon RX 480 Nitro+ 8GB GDDR5
- 64GB Corsair Vengeance DDR4 RAM
- EVGA 500W Power Supply
- WD Blue 1TB @ 7200RPM
- Samsung 840 EVO 500GB SSD
- Windows 7 Ultimate

I could <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on the blue screen, and start the Task Manager, but I didn't see anything running that shouldn't have been.  I do have a backup from before the computer started acting up, but I would prefer to not have to resort to that, if necessary.

Comment: If you wait long enough, will it log in actually? How long are we talking about here to wait?

Comment: Does anything odd show up in the event log pertaining to the boot up/login event? Generally it'll tell you exactly what's slowing you down, so posting that data would also be helpful.

Comment: It will log in, yes.  It takes about 15-20 seconds for Welcome to disappear an 30-45 seconds for the blue screen to disappear.  After the 30-45 seconds, my desktop appears, the Windows chime plays, and it acts like nothing happened.

Comment: Try running msconfig and disabling extra stuff from starting up. If you notice that this improves back to where you were before then go back and try disabling one program at a time from starting until you find one that affects the startup most. If you need help for how to run msconfig ask

Answer (score 0):

Whelp, I found the answer.

I went into the Event Log as Dooley_labs suggested, and I saw several things pertaining to a device called "Fo€n", which is what I named my phone. I was charging it off the tower, but I didn't realize it was sharing data.

I unplugged, restarted, and, completely normal startup. No issues with blue screens, etc.

In short: make sure your Galaxy Light is unplugged before booting.